# Method taking the parameter is reference to an array of references to values

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method taking that only parameter is a reference to an array of references to values, and return true if the references stored in the array refer to the same exact number object.

Does "reference to an array of references to values" mean just "array of something"? 
like Type[] a = new Type[]; ?

And, how do I check the number object stored in the array? I guess I need to use the for loop?

Comment: I guess you are talking about an array of a Type. Something like Person[]. This is a person array that stores instances(references) of Persons. You can pass this array which holds references to different instances

Comment: If someone uses very exact terminology, then e.g. a variable doesn't store a Person, but a "reference to a Person", as the Person data aren't found in the variable, but somewhere on the heap, and the variable just somehow references the Person object on the heap. Usually we omit that phrase, as in Java it's always like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the array and check if all the objects are `==` to each other:

```
public static boolean allSame(Object[] arr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use equals instead of operators while comparing objects.

Comment: @Sekar not in this case - OP requests that "return true if the references stored in the array refer to **the same exact number object**". That's what `==` does, not `equals`.